# Excel Error Trace IF nested statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Am trying to trace back an error on a spreadsheet, but am having difficulties tracing it. Here is the code that is present on the cell:

```
=IF($A$4="","N/A",
IF(OR('Manual Input'!$I$6="ENTER ENGAGEMENT LETTER DATE 
(YYYY/MM/DD)",'Manual Input'!$I$6=""),"SEE REVIEW PERIOD START DATE",
IF(AF4="No",
IF(AND(
IF(AND(TRIM(I4)<>"NA",TRIM(I4)<>"N/A",TRIM(I4<>"None"),
MAX(IF(ISTEXT(I4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(I4)),I4),IF(ISTEXT(G4),DATEVALUE(TRI
M(G4)),G4))>($AQ$1-365),IF(ISTEXT(G4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(G4)),G4)>($AQ$1-365)),
IF(ISTEXT(G4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(G4)),G4)
<=IF(ISTEXT(T4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(T4)),T4),TRIM(T4),
IF(AND(TRIM(I4)<>"NA",TRIM(I4)<>"N/A",TRIM(I4)
<>"None"),IF(ISTEXT(I4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(I4)),I4)
<=IF(ISTEXT(T4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(T4)),T4),
OR(TRIM(I4)="NA",TRIM(I4)="N/A",TRIM(I4)="None")),
IF(ISTEXT(G4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(G4)),G4)<=IF(AND(TRIM(U4)<>"NA",TRIM(U4)
<>"N/A"),IF(ISTEXT(U4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(U4)),U4),TRIM(U4)),
IF(ISTEXT(G4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(G4)),G4)<=IF(AND(TRIM(V4)<>"NA",TRIM(V4)
<>"N/A"),IF(ISTEXT(V4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(V4)),V4),TRIM(V4)),
IF(ISTEXT(G4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(G4)),G4)<=IF(AND(TRIM(W4)<>"NA",TRIM(W4)
<>"N/A"),IF(ISTEXT(W4),DATEVALUE(TRIM(W4)),W4),TRIM(W4))),
"Yes","No"),"INVALID VALUES")))
```

I keep getting a value error. I tried running the Evaluate formula and the following is the sequence before the error happens:

```
IF(FALSE, #N/A, IF(FALSE, #N/A, IF(TRUE, IF(AND(TRUE, TRUE, "2017/04/24", 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), "Yes, "No"), "Invalid")))
```

I know that the date is supposed to be a True/False, but am not sure how to correct it. Any help would be good.
Data:
I4 = NA,    G4 = 2017/4/20,   AQ1 = 2017/03/01
T4=2017/4/24,    U4=2017/4/26,    V4=NA

Additionally, on clicking error checking, it states that "The value used on the formula is of wrong data type"

Comment: Why not use VBA? This is almost too convoluted to debug. If you really want to debug it, find a way of displaying the formula in a format where indentation shows logical structure.

Comment: break your IF formula down into the individual if formulas (place one each in its own separate cells.  Test each one and see which one fails.

Comment: AND(TRUE, TRUE, "2017/04/24", TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE) may be your problem.  Not sure how AND will evaluated "2017/04/24",  AND is looking for a logical (TRUE or FALSE)  or number but you are supplying TEXT

Comment: @ForwardEd, I didn't make the template. Am just trying to figure out where it went wrong. I personally would have preferred VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. I traced the error back to an AND statement issue.